# App theme not changing with preference selected?

Tags: android

this is my first time dabbling in using preferences to change an apps theme, and I can't seem to get this working correctly. Here's my code:

MainActivity.Java onCreate Method

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SharedPreferences getPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
        String values = getPrefs.getString("list","1");
        if(values.contentEquals("1")){
            setTheme(R.style.Holo_Dark);

        }else if(values.contentEquals("2")){
            setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);

        }

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
                getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
        mTitle = getTitle();

        // Set up the drawer.
        mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
                R.id.navigation_drawer,
                (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));

        TextView medEntry = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.med_name);

       /* medEntry.setOnFocusListener(new FocusListner(){

        }); */

    }
```

Prefs.Java:

```
public class Prefs extends PreferenceActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){



        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs);

    }
}
```

array.xml for the prefs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="list">

        <item>Dark</item>
        <item>Light</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="lValues">
        <item>1</item>
        <item>2</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

styles.xml:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->

    </style>
    <style name="Holo_Dark" parent="android:Theme.Holo">

    </style>

</resources>
```

and my Manifest:

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".Prefs"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PREFS" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
if(values.equals("1")
```

instead of

```
if(values.contentEquals("1"))
```

Comment: this didn't change the result

Comment: post the code where you commit values to editor may be there is only one value in list string throughout the app that's why you see the same theme

Comment: The values are in array.xml as seen above and the values can be seen committed in prefs.java as seen above @ravi sharma

Answer (score 0):

Provide a String, maybe set up a constant to minimize the risk of typos. 
And don't forget to un- and reinstall the app if you messed something up in the prefs.